# How to Access AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: window as! UIWindowScene) Callbacks or Delegate Methods

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I'm implementing `AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in:)`, I can't find the callbacks to find out what option a user selected such as cancel/dismiss/swipe down to dismiss, cancel subscription, purchase subscription, etc. I need to run some code based on these 3 situations. How do I access the callbacks or delegate functions?

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first {
    Task {
        do {
            try await AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: window as! UIWindowScene)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about checking the subscription statuses before and after the call?

Comment: Checking beforehand isn't the issue. I use revenuecat for that. I can use it to check afterwards too. But how do I know when the call is over?

Comment: `showManageSubscriptions` is `async throws`. `try await` it, and the next line of code will be executed when it's done.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Would you mind adding that as an answer? I think it'll help the next person. I'm sure there are other people who will come across this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run code after the user is done with the manage subscriptions sheet, just put that code after the `showManageSubscriptions` call.

To distinguish between what the user has done in the manage subscriptions sheetm you can check your subscriptions' statuses before and after the `showManageSubscriptions` call, and compare.

```
do {
    let before = ... // get subscription status before
    try await AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: window as! UIWindowScene)
    let after = ... // get subscription status after
    // compare before and after
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```